# injecting deleted files while codegen

Tags: dsl, xtext, language-server-protocol

using this code to fetch files for codegen from filesystem

```
public void executeCommand(Resource resource, Document document, ILanguageServerAccess access,
            ExecuteCommandParams params) {

        JavaIoFileSystemAccess fileSystemAccess = getFileSystemAccess(params);

        final Function<ILanguageServerAccess.IndexContext, Boolean> func = (
                ILanguageServerAccess.IndexContext ctxt) -> {
            for (final IResourceDescription rd : ctxt.getIndex().getAllResourceDescriptions()) {
                if (isGenerate(rd)) {

                    Resource res = getResource(access, rd);

                    if (res != null) {
                        generator.doGenerate(res, fileSystemAccess, new GeneratorContext());
                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        };

        access.doReadIndex(func);
    }
```

this code is returning deleted files of filesystem.

Expecting updated files from filesystem with deleted files filtered

Comment: i propose you debug why file is not removed from  getIndex

Comment: also re reproducing unit test would be nice

Comment: debugging place e.g. org.eclipse.xtext.build.Indexer.computeAndIndexAffected(BuildRequest, BuildContext)

Comment: did some debugging, 
found that this build is only executing when opening or closing the file in theia not while creating or deleting the file.

Comment: did you check why? which events are sent to server on delete? org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl.didChangeWatchedFiles(DidChangeWatchedFilesParams) i would expect

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to language client options, it should be similar to below :

```
function createClientOptions(): LanguageClientOptions {
    return {
        documentSelector: ["your extension"], synchronize: {
            fileEvents: workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.*")
        }
    };
}
```

Particularly in this case, i think you are missing createFileSystemWatcher.
Also if not using the latest version of Theia then please update.